# Jira Development Panel is not working in Gitlab integration

Tags: gitlab, jira

I can only see it as web links and comment. Where do I do wrong? I use Gitlab's free version.

[image]

Comment: Do you use the cloud or self-hosted version for jira/gitlab? Also which versions are you using (as you need gitlab to be at least at 13.4 for this to work on free)?

Comment: It 's SAAS. Both of them are cloud.

Comment: And the links dont work or where is the problem with the links shown?

Comment: It should be added information under the Development section. You can see the black rectangle

Comment: If the linked repository/ group is empty with no commits etc, everything seems correct. Otherwise, you should check what repository you have linked and if you implemented the necessary naming convention: https://support.atlassian.com/jira-software-cloud/docs/reference-issues-in-your-development-work/